# Code to find first occurence and return 0 if no occurence and then append new column onto csv (python)

Tags: python, string, loops, csv, if-statement

I am trying to extract values inside a column in a csv. Here is my code so far:

````
```code```
import csv
with open('Cash_Statement_Pier21 accounts 2019c.csv') as csv_file:
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
line_count = 0
for row in csv_reader:
    for line in row:
        index = line.find('@')
        if index != -1:
            print(line[index+2:index+7])
        else:
            index = line.find('RATE')
            if index != -1:
                print(line[index +2])
````

However, this code fails for lines with multiple "@"s and it only prints out the list in python. How
would I append this code such that it a) only takes into account the first "@" on every line and b) 
creates a new column in my csv?

Thanks so much in advance!

*EDIT* SAMPLE INPUT (  seperated lines for readability)
NOVO NORDISK A/S    216757.000 SHS @ 5.15000000 EXDTE-22MAR19 PAYDTE-26MAR19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%

NOVO NORDISK A/S    205395.000 SHS @ 3.00000000 EXDTE-16AUG19 PAYDTE-20AUG19 TAXABLE RECLAIMABLE TAXED AT .270000%

NOVO NORDISK A/S    TAX RECLAIM PAID 79000.000 EX-DT:20MAR15 PY-DT:24MAR15 CURRENCY TIP # 1150790014348

PING AN INSURANCE GROUP CO OF HK/02318   1184000.000 SHS @ 1.28414399EXDTE-23MAY19 PAYDTE-28JUN19 TAXABLE AT ISSUE RATE .100000%

```
BANK CENTRAL ASIA TBK PT    3314200.000 SHS @ 100.00000000 EXDTE-06DEC19 PAYDTE-20DEC19 TAXABLE AT ISSUE RATE .200000%
```

[image: SAMPLE OUTPUT]

Comment: Hi Joel, could you provide a sample input and sample output to make things even clearer? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample input data as text, not as a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different problems here.

1. How to only process first `@` or each line?

   I will assume that despite what you have shown, you are actually processing a true csv file with more than one field per row and only want to process the first **field** containing a `@` caracter. If you do not want to search for `RATE` if you have found `@`, it is trivial: just add a `break` statement:

   ```
   for row in csv_reader:
       for line in row:
           index = line.find('@')
           if index != -1:
               print(line[index+2:index+7])
               break                         // ignore any other field in that row
           else:
               ...
   ```

   If you want to process the first `@` *and* the first `RATE` on each row, you will have to use a boolean to ignore any `@` but the first, but still continue up to a `RATE`:

   ```
   for row in csv_reader:
       first = True
       for line in row:
           if first:
               index = line.find('@')
               if index != -1:
                   print(line[index+2:index+7])
                   first = False                         // ignore any other field in that row
          else:
               ...
   ```
2. How to add a new field to a CSV?

   A CSV is a text file. The only reliable way to change it is to rewrite everything on a temporary file and when done remove the old file (or rename it as a backup) and rename the temporary to the original name. More or less (only showing high level):

   ```
   ok = False
   with open('Cash_Statement_Pier21 accounts 2019c.csv') as csv_file:
       with open('Cash_Statement_Pier21 accounts 2019c.tmp', 'w',', newline='') as out_file:
           csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
           csv_writer = csv.writer(out_file, delimiter=')
           for row in csv_reader:
               ...
               row.append(new_column_value)
               csv_writer.writerow(row)
       ok = True
   if ok:     // do not rename if an error occured...
       os.remove('Cash_Statement_Pier21 accounts 2019c.csv')
       os.rename('Cash_Statement_Pier21 accounts 2019c.tmp',
                 'Cash_Statement_Pier21 accounts 2019c.csv)'
   ```

   We have to wait after the end of the `with` block to execute the rename, because some OS may refuse to remove or rename an open file.

Comment: Thanks. Apologies, your first assumption was correct and the code worked. The part of saving the csv does not work with error: TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

Comment: My bad... `newline = ''` is a parameter of the `open` function. Post edited

Comment: Thanks so much! really appreciate the help